# Monitor won't turn on

Tags: display, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, repair

I have an Acer flatscreen that works properly (I've tested it), connected to a graphics card that also works properly (also has been tested), and still it does not respond when I turn the computer on (which also works, I get green lights, and one beep).

The motherboard has onboard video as well. I've unplugged my graphics card and connected my monitor to the onboard video port. It still doesn't respond.

I've unplugged all the PCI devices and replaced them. This doesn't work. (Though, I had forgotten about the mobo battery)

I'm thinking I need a new power supply. It's the only thing I've been able to conclude in all the searches I've done so far.

Can someone help?

Comment: And when did this begin to happen?  was any of this all working together before?  Did you check for bent pins? Inspect each of the ports carefully? Did you check again your power connection to the grafics card?   It would really help in your situation to have a different monitor, did you use a different computer to test the graphics card?

Comment: Did you test the video cable?

Comment: It was working before just fine. I hadn't used it for about a month, and decided to give the computer to my mom. While setting it up (last week), I discovered this problem. The card is a Galaxy brand Nvidia GeForce GT 440, and does not have a power connector to the card. I've tested both the monitor and graphics card in my current computer, and they both work fine. I haven't looked for bent pins, but I'll check it out.

Comment: Yes, I tested the cable when I tested the monitor on another computer. They both worked fine.